# What does the namespace sentence in the Python Zen mean?

Tags: python, theory

I have been using Python as my go-to programming language for quite some time now. Today, I ended up doing `import this` and re-reading the Zen of Python by Tim Peters. Lately, I have also been interested in designing languages and programming language theory- so the same things are making more and more sense.

However, the last line in the Zen is entirely mystical to me at the moment. I know the Zens of Python are not the part of the language itself, but I'm curious as to what it could mean or imply.

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Comment: The more you restrict the scope of your object (functions, variables...) the better !?